# Cucumber Execution Error Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

Hello every body i am working on a project in which have to implement cucumber with selenium when i run my code following error message is shown 
I have JDK 7 installed and i am using Jars in image

[image]

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(Ljava/util/Properties;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:32)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**Feature is :** 
Feature: Check addition in Google calculator
   In order to verify that google calculator work correctly
   As a user of google
   I should be able to get correct addition result

Scenario: Addition
   Given I open google
   When I enter "2+2" in search textbox
   Then I should get result as "4"

```
**Cucumber Steps Class IS :** 


    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;

        import cucumber.api.java.After;
        import cucumber.api.java.Before;
        import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
        import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
        import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

        public class googleCalcStepDefinition {


            protected WebDriver driver;

             @Before
                public void setup() {
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }

            @Given("^I open google$")
            public void I_open_google() {
                //Set implicit wait of 10 seconds and launch google
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
            }

            @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
            public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String additionTerms) {
                //Write term in google textbox
                WebElement googleTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
                googleTextBox.sendKeys(additionTerms);

                //Click on searchButton
                WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
                searchButton.click();
            }

            @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
            public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
                //Get result from calculator
                WebElement calculatorTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("cwos"));
                String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();

                //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4
                Assert.assertEquals(result, expectedResult);

                driver.close();
            }

             @After
                public void closeBrowser() {
                    driver.quit();
             }

        }


        **Junit Runner Class is :** 

            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

            import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

            import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;;

            @RunWith(Cucumber.class)


 @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/"},glue = {"src/googleCalcStepDefinition.java"})
            public class googleCalcTest {
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible jar files in your classpath

Comment: can you please tell me which jars then i must use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed This issue just by installing JDK8 64 bit and Eclipse LUNA 64 bit and then using following jars 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions has no constructor which accepts parameters Properties and String. Cucumber libraries you are using do not support this.

Try using something like below.

```
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
      features = "<path to feature file>",
      glue = "src/googleCalcStepDefinition.java"
    )
    public class googleCalcTest {
    }
```

Comment: edited my answer, there was a bracket missing. Could you try?

Comment: i added them my self still same error message shown

Comment: Btw, feautues should have value as ''path to feature file" , I see you are giving a java file name. Feature files generally have extension of .feature

Comment: Can you Please share with me any working test project which is working fine on your machine so that i can verify its not JAR compliance issue ?

Comment: i made that change too and edited the code renamed feature as features = {"src/"}

Comment: pls specify feature file name for value against features. The jars you need for code I have posted are                                               cucumber-java-1.1.8.jar ,  
cucumber-junit-1.1.8.jar ,  
cucumber-core-1.1.8.jar, 
cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar, 
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar, 
gherkin-2.12.2.jar, 
junit-4.11.jar

Comment: Pls remove cucumber-junit-1.1.3.jar and gherkin-2.10.0.jar from the classpath